# cURL - How do i disable it requesting a response

Tags: php, curl, timeout, response

im using a cURL script to post parameters to pages on my others sites as a update for clients, my problem is that my curl script stops while its waiting from a response to one site before continuing on to the other sites, also if one page time outs it takes ages to get on to the next, ive tryed using curl_setopt to set connectiontimeout and timeout to 0 and that doesnt work on the responses side of my problem. So getting down to it, how do i stop curl waiting for a response from the target server before moving on to the next one?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Well, setting connection timeout to 0 means to make them wait indefinitely...

Comment: oh thanks, well what do u recommend me to do?

Comment: What are you doing with your cURL request?  Is it a process that would be better handled by a scheduled task to prevent it from stalling up the user browsing as it waits for the response?

Comment: umm, i dont really understand your question but yes whats happening is its stalling if the targets web server is slow or if the domains been closed, and once the action is done there is no response so i dont really need to wait for one.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should check response, to know if everything went OK or give a second try. Solution might be to run multiple curl request at once: **[curl_multi_init](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)**, and if you really don't want to wait, set small timeout (but not too small, give some time to fetch DNS record and send request, try with `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`) and set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to `true` (or `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `HEAD`), so curl won't wait to get whole response.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Could you give me a example of how to set the opts because im new the cURL and every time i try i get errors :S

Comment: hi, i was just reading into curl_multi_init, the problem with that method is i actually dont know how many clients i have, i store all my clients along with there site in a MySQL database, then pull there information in a query and execute accordingly, so i can create a certain amount of curl inits, it has to be dynamic.